# jquery mobile popup sends wrong hash url when using angularjs & MVC ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I saw forum posts that basically say that jquery mobile does not play well with angular. I tried a suggested "angular-adapter", but could not get that to work. I am wondering if there is another way?

Another clue, when the angular grid runs, its url is:
http://localhost:52327/MbsaWorkoutName/PerformWorkouts
and when the button is clicked and dosnt work, it creates a url like this:
http://localhost:52327/MbsaWorkoutName/PerformWorkouts#/popupPanel

Another clue is that if i take this "data-ng-controller="userController" " out of the angular div, the button works, if i change the name in the "app.controller to something like ('userControllerXXX') in the custom angular js file, the button works.

the popup button works on all the other pages except this one that loads my angular code, so, ajax=false is not of use to me.

For the primary code and more on this issue - [jquery mobile popup does not work with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533260/jquery-mobile-popup-does-not-work-with-angular)

if more code is needed, please let me know.

thanks for any help and/or advice ...